# dealing with large CSV files in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, extjs, d3.js, client-server

I need some advices from you guys. I am bit confused about some problems i have when I am trying to deal with a large csv file. What I am doing now days is that I am using Javascript (client side language) to display some charts based on the csv file data. I am using D3 and Extjs 4.2 to do that.

The problem is that when I am trying to deal with large csv file who contain 10000 lines and at least 5 columns (Search in the file and doing a lot calculation based on the values in the columns ), it takes a lot of time and some times the browser get crushed. I want some advices about what I have to do to improve the application's performance.

Is it normal to do complex calculations with javascript or javascript is not capable to do complex calculations?

**some explanation:**

in fact, each line in the csv file contain at least 5 columns (keyword, value1,value2...value4) and i need to draw an Axe for each column (value:1...4) except the first one(keyword): *parallel coordinates in d3*.
for each column, when i have keywords with the same value, i have to add to coordinate X (dx), for example:
when i have 3 keywords who have the same value in the second column-for example-, i place the first one in p(x,y), the second in p(x+dx,y) and the third in the p(x-dx,y), so that they will be next to each other and not over each other in the graph.
so that i need to load all the file lines and for each column i have to search the duplicated values to calculate its coordinates x,y and then save them in an array because i need to use them later.
in my application.
on other hand, i have a tool to select an area around each Axe -lasso select- to get all the points are in that area. here for each time i use lasso tool i have to search for each value if it is in the area or not and when i have 10000 line, that would take long time to do it.

Comment: I think you will need to show your code before anyone can help with this.

Comment: i thought about that but i have about 2500 lines of code in different js and html files so it is bit hard to show it in a clear way "as i think".. thanks

Comment: Is there any way of loading parts of the csv as and when needed.  For instance, in an application I built, rather than loading everything from 1 csv, there was a csv for each year of my dataset, and it loaded each as and when required...

Comment: thanks for answer Robinal and codebox. to be more clear and to answer your question, i updated my post

Comment: I think that you can use a data manipulation library ([Miso Dataset, for example](http://misoproject.com/dataset/)) to do some of those calculations (aggregation, group by column, min, max, filter). This helps with the performance issue because the routines in the library will be optimized for that kind of tasks. 10k is not that huge anyway.

Comment: yea i know 10k is not so huge but till now, my application could not deal with 10k. i want to improve it then use more large file because later i must use csv file of 100k.
Thanks Pablo for your suggestion, i am going now to give it a try :).

Comment: Keep in mind that Javascript is terrible when it comes to the precision of even simple arithmetic operations. If you need the numbers to be correct, I would advise doing any calculations before you give the data to d3.

Comment: @Lars, thanks for your advice, i will try to use Miso Dataset library (as Pablo) to do the calculations on the data before i pass them to D3 library.